# pointer for sensor_msgs::LaserScan

Tags: laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So,

I have sensor_msgs::LaserScanPtr&  scan_msg being passed in a function.
the first line is
BOOST::ASSERT(!scan_msg);
the second line is
BOOST::ASSERT(!scan_msg->ranges);

Problem:
it has a compilation error : ! not defined for shared pointer
so, I make a change
BOOST::ASSERT(!scan_msg->ranges.get())
Now it has compilation error : get not defined for ranges .

What am I supposed to do to see if ranges is not empty ??? (I have considered operator precendence and applied all the parenthesis I could, to no avail).

~Cheers!
navderm

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53372/pointer-for-sensor_msgs::laserscan/) by [navderm](https://answers.ros.org/users/984/navderm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2013-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The **ranges** field is just a **std::vector**. Try this:

```
if (scan_msg->ranges.empty()) { ... }
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3